# Insert Data Paste Error on other Computers

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I have finished a small Project at work and distributed the File to my coworkers.
I saved the file as .xlsm to enable makros. I have used the code for about 2 weeks now and never had any problems with it.

However when i sent them to my Coworkers one makro doesnt work.
I have multiple makros in the File and only one of them doesnt work anymore so i believe its the makros problem and not the new Excel version:

```
Sub Loomisinsert()

    'Deletes old Data and inserts new


    Sheets("MSE").Range("B2:J1000").Clear
    Sheets("MSE").Range("B2:B2").Select
    Sheets("MSE").Paste


    'deletes unnecessary data

    Sheets("MSE").Range("K3:N5000").Delete
    Sheets("MSE").Range("P3:Q5000").Delete
    Sheets("MSE").Range("S3:U5000").Delete
    Sheets("MSE").Range("L3:L5000").Delete


End Sub
```

The user is only supposed to copy Data from another Workbook and use an excel button to insert the data at the right place and delete the correct cells.

As you can see i tried to specify which sheet to use for each command. And it works fine for me but not on my Coworkers Computer.
They have Excel 2013 and 2010 the same i use.

Comment: what are you copying? you haven't selected anything in the script - therefore excel will simply copy the last clipboard entry from the user in "B2" - if the user's clipboard is empty there is nothing to paste

Comment: can you explain what you mean with *"doesnt work"*? It does nothing? It does something wrong? It throws a runtime error? Have you tried to use the Debugger?

Comment: @Jo.lass Yes the User copies Data from another Worksheet then goes to my Worksheet and the formula is supposed to replace the old Data with the new. I mentioned it at the bottom of the Question

Comment: @FunThomas An Error message Paste error its in the Title

Comment: Using the `Clear`-command clears also the `Paste-Buffer`.

Comment: You paste something but there is no cop in the code...

Comment: @Error1004 I mentioned in the Question the User copies the data manually from another file and then uses my makro to insert it here

Comment: @Cedric in my opinion there is no need to use .paste in the code if the user paste manually.

Comment: @Error1004 I want to make it as easy as possible for my coworkers because they are really not that tech savvy. Theyre supposed to just press a button and it would insert the data, remove uncecessary data .

Answer (score 0):

Below are some suggestions. Modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loomisinsert()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Deletes old Data and inserts new
        .Range("B2:J1000").Clear
        .Range("B5").Copy .Range("B2") '<- Easy way to copy - paste

        'Deletes unnecessary data
        .Range("K3:N5000,P3:Q5000,S3:U5000").Clear'<- Does not need to use "L3:L5000" because included in "K3:N5000". Additionally, have in mind that *.Delete* may cause problem with columns & rows. It s more preferable to use *.Clear* or *.Clearcontents*. *.Clear* used to clear both formats and value. In the other hand *.Cleatcontents* just empty the cell from value.

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, the user selects some data from another workbook, presses copy and then, instead of pasting the data, presses a button.